# Closing a file when looping creates that file

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm looping through the lines of a text file `test.fasta`, and when I get to a line of `format1`, I want to create a `newFile1`, skip a line, then write the following lines of `f` to `newFile1` until I get to another line of `format1`, at which point I want to close `newFile1`, create `newfile2` etc.

What I have so far:

```
import re

with open('test.fasta', 'r') as seqs:

    seqFile = (open('throwaway.txt', 'a+'))

    for line in seqs:
        if re.search('^>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]', line):
            seqFile.close()
            seqFile = open('%s.fasta' % line, 'a+')
            seqs.next()
        else:
            seqFile.write('%s' % line)

    seqFile.close()
```

This code works and the output is what I expect. The trouble is that before I start the loop, I need to create that `throwaway.txt` file so that the first iteration of my loop doesn't fail because `seqFile` doesn't exist. If I don't include the `seqFile.close()` where it is, then I'm just leaving a bunch of files open.

I can add in an `if` statement that only handles the first iteration where there's no file open, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: `a+` creates a new file if the file is not found. What were you thinking?

Comment: I was thinking I want to create a bunch of new files - that's working as intended. That's not the problem, the problem is that I want to be able to close the files after I'm done with them as part of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the most straightforward way to avoid relying on the presence of the dummy file is to just catch that exception on the first time through the loop when you try to call `close`:

```
if re.search('^>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]', line):
  try:
    seqFile.close()
  except NameError: # Assuming you haven't set seqFile else where before the first time through the loop
    pass
  seqFile = open('%s.fasta' % line, 'a+')
  # Do everything else you were going to do
```

Comment: Excellent - this works! I ended up putting `seqFile = None` outside the loop, then added `if seqFile: seqfile.close()` inside the loop. Your way is probably more efficient ultimately... not sure why you were voted down.

Comment: @kevbonham I'm glad if it helps.  As a side note (if this scenario hasn't come up in your thinking yet, but it may have) - if the `test.fasta` file starts with a line that does not match that regular expression, you're going to be either actually writing data to the throwaway file (in your original version) or throwing an uncaught NameError exception (in this version) from the `else` side of that conditional.

Comment: Yes, good point. This is a very specific use-case and the file does indeed start with that regular expression. However, I'm still pretty new at this and would love to learn best practices - how would you deal with a situation in which the first line might not match?

Comment: @kevbonham That depends very much on your requirements.  The intent of your code appears to be to partition a large file into a group of smaller "records" which are identified by those special lines; if your requirements are such that you can throw away truncated "records" which might appear at the beginning, a similar `try`/`except NameError` block can be applied to the `seqFile.write` statement.  Alternatively, there may be an error log to which you need to write those orphaned lines.  It all depends on your requirements.